# How can I delete all my personal files on my Mac so they are not recoverable

Tags: mac

I have to return my work laptop soon and would like to delete all my personal files so they are not recoverable at all.

I was thinking of using the terminal command `rm –rf /` but I'm not sure if this would leave the computer in a state that my company could recover it from.

Comment: While this is not a technical issue, please consider: Are you *allowed* to wipe everything on the computer? If it is a work computer, your employer may require you to keep installed software, work results, emails etc. intact on the computer. This in turn will make secure deletion very difficult. Talk to your employer first (and next time, avoid putting personal files on a work computer :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

Is the Mac FileVault encrypted?
If so, a simple re-install of the OS from Internet Recovery is sufficient to make your data irrecoverable. Once the encryption keys are gone, that's it, no recovery.

No need to do any kind of 'military-grade' erasure process, FileVault is sufficient.

Also, compared to any 'secure erase' process, if you don't use FileVault, it would still be quicker to enable it now, wait until it's finished, then proceed as above.

See [Apple KB - What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065) to see what else you should do to dissociate yourself from the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete your files, or wipe the entire drive; operating system as well?

The latter is easy.  Burn one of [these](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/top-5-linux-system-rescue-cds) on a CD.  Boot onto the CD and mount any drives you want to wipe; they will probably all be mounted automatically anyway.  Say you want to wipe /dev/sda, then you run

```
dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sda
```

This will take a very long time, but it overwrites every bit of the drive with a random bit. You would have to be a national security risk for anyone to bother trying to recover the data on that drive.

Comment: I would say wipe the enitre drive. While this is an easy solution I dont have a cd drive and would prefer a solution that doesnt require one.

Comment: It seems you can just run it on your mac as is. https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_wipe_a_hard_drive_clean_in_Linux.  Note that according to this, you should use /dev/urandom for security reasons.

Comment: Wiping the entire drive probably would *not* "leave the computer in a state that my company could recover it from," unless they have an image of the drive. See also https://www.groovypost.com/howto/securely-delete-files-mac/